Darlington control with Op Amp and DAC
The purpose of my circuit is to control(current) a servo motor with the 4096 steps of the DAC MCP4725. Currently this circut is not turning on the NPN Darlington, I don't know why that.
The DAC is working properly, generating from 0 to 3.3V.


Why would you take the output of unused opamp (U39B) and connect it to ground?  Me thinks U39 is toast.

Are you using a high-side NPN as both the current sensing resistance and the drive?

The LM393 is a dual comparator with open-collector output. You'll need to replace it with an op-amp eg. LM358  if you want a stable output voltage in that circuit.
And fix the unused amplifier's connections. The app notes have suggestions on what to do with unused amplifiers and that is not one of them. It's doing nothing to the '393 but with an op-amp you have a 50:50 chance of it getting really hot and possibly damaging itself.
Even if it is fixed such that it 'works', this circuit will simply provide a 0-3.3v regulated voltage to the motor. Most of the power will be wasted in the Darlington. If you want to control current you'll need to take feedback from a low-side current sense resistor.
Since the 3.3V voltage is rather high, unless you divide the input down you'll get quite a bit of dissipation in the sense resistor. Eg. for 8A you'd get >26W dissipation in the resistor.
The Darlington is unlikely to be able to provide anything like 8A safely in a linear mode due to power dissipation and SOA considerations. More like 1A. There's a reason why we usually go to switching circuits (usually with MOSFETs in this voltage/current range) when the power is higher than a few watts and you've got more than 100W.

you are right the circuit only can provide 0-3.3v, it's already tested, so for sure I have to move to another solution, probably a MOSFET type.

Besides the trivial mistake of terminating the unused amplifier as the Rat suggested. Your circuit is a disaster and will not work the way you think it should work.
First, this circuit does not control current. It will control voltage from about 0V to (almost) 1.9V. Put a meter across the motor if you don't believe me.
This is because you have a voltage-follower configuration and only 3.3V to work with. Even if you hypothetically had the full voltage to control like, this, voltage-mode motor control is poor performance.
A better solution would be to PWM the transistor configured as a common-emitter like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This circuit is much more efficient and easier to modulate the speed of the motor.
If you still insist on your approach - DAC controlling analog motor current, you would have to do something like this:

simulate this circuit
This circuit will actually regulate analog current. The values I selected will give 1A of motor current at full scale (3.3V = 1A). You may have to tweak R1 for different transconductance gain. C1 and R2 are for stability. May not be needed in practice and may need values adjusted based on your application and dynamics. C2 helps with noise immunity and stability. Probably not needed in practice because the motor will eat any instability presented at this node.
I still recommend the PWM approach - more efficient and you don't have to deal with the thermal management of Q1.

+1 to @Spehro for writing the description at the same time I was drafting the circuit.

I like the PWM option but handling the high side, can I use the same schematic but inverted with a Darlington PNP? What about just use a MOSFET P-channel instead of a Darlington? talking in mind that I must take care to dissipate the less heat as possible.

@johnnytolengo PWM technique will dissipate the least heat in any case. You can use a PNP Darlington. But a Pmosfet will be better (lower conduction losses which is where your dominant heat comes from).

@johnnytolengo Here's some ideas: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/716172/mosfet-driver-totem-pole-or-npn-self-biasing-turn-off-circuit/716211?noredirect=1#comment1905307_716211

you are right, I will go with the N-Channel mosfet driven by PWM. My question is how hot will be the transistor at 2,6,8 Amps? it's my first time running high current, and I don't know if I will need to put there a heatsink or not and how large.

I need to move an DC Actuator max 8A.

@johnnytolengo That should be another question. But it's going to be Rds(ON)*Amps^2 (dominant heat factor) + switching losses (which when the gate is driven correctly, will be quite low. This depends mostly on switching frequency (higher is worse) and how fast you can charge and discharge the gate in a switching cycle).
